How to export Excel tables to quoted csv files using javascript and Script Lab?
A little over a year ago I wrote a script in Script Lab that would export all of the tables on the active worksheet to individual quoted csv files.
I was running this in M365 Excel on the Desktop.
This worked fine at the time, and again this past April.
When run, the table name was logged to the console, and the files were downloaded to the default Downloads folder on the computer.
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {

    exportAllTablesToCSV();

    console.log("Exporting all tables on current worksheet to quoted csv files.");

    await context.sync();
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}

// Function to export a table to a CSV file
async function exportTableToCSV(table, tableName, fileNamePrefix, fileNameSuffix) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
        const dataBodyRange = sheet.tables.getItem(tableName).getRange();

        dataBodyRange.load("values");

        await context.sync();

        const fileName = fileNamePrefix + String(tableName).replace(/Table_/g, "") + fileNameSuffix + ".csv";

        const csvData = dataBodyRange.values
          .map((row) => {
            const quotedRow = row.map((cell) => {
              // Quote and escape existing double quotes
              return '"' + String(cell).replace(/"/g, '""') + '"';
            });
            return quotedRow.join(",");
          })
          .join("\n");

        const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: "text/csv" });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

        // Wait for the download to complete before resolving
        // Adjust the delay as needed
        await new Promise((innerResolve) => setTimeout(innerResolve, 1000));

        console.log("Exported " + tableName + " as " + fileName);

        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        document.body.removeChild(a);

        resolve();
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}

// Function to export all tables on the active worksheet to CSV
async function exportAllTablesToCSV() {
  try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
      const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
      const tables = sheet.tables.load("items/name");
      const currentDate = new Date()
        .toISOString()
        .slice(0, 10)
        .replace(/-/g, "");

      const fileNamePrefix = "Pre_";
      const fileNameSuffix = "_" + currentDate;

      await context.sync();

      for (const table of tables.items) {
        const tableName = table.name;
        await exportTableToCSV(table, tableName, fileNamePrefix, fileNameSuffix);
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

Now, however, after the script runs with no errors, no files are generated in the Downloads folder.
There is no record of their existence in the browser Downloads history.
I can also not find any evidence that the files are being downloaded somewhere else either.
I have tried this not only in the latest Excel Desktop, but also in Excel Online in Edge, Chrome, and Firefox.
I have also tried this on multiple machines, both Windows 10 and 11.
I have tried adding an event listener for the click() event, which is firing.
(code not included above)
The basic functionality comes from
        const blob = new Blob([csvData], { type: "text/csv" });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.click();

And I've found a number of references to this construction via web searches (though all are generally older).
So I tried the following proof-of-concept
$("#run").on("click", () => tryCatch(run));

async function run() {
  await Excel.run(async (context) => {
    const sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();

    // Create a blob with some data
    const data = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], { type: "text/plain" });

    // Create a URL for the blob
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(data);

    // Create an <a> element
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = url;
    link.download = "example.txt"; // Specify the filename

    // Append the link to the document (optional, if you want to make it visible)
    document.body.appendChild(link);

    // Trigger the download
    link.click();

    console.log("link clicked");

    // Clean up by revoking the object URL after a delay
    setTimeout(() => {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      document.body.removeChild(link); // Remove the link from the document
    }, 3000);

    await context.sync();
  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}

This also does not generate a download, but there are no apparent errors generated when the script runs.
So,

can anyone else get these scripts to work?

any idea what might be going on?
was there a change made to Office.js that I'm not seeing documented somewhere when I search?


Any insights appreciated.

I'm surprised that this ever worked. It looks like a way to evade the general rule that web applications should not be able to save to the user's machine (except for certain special exceptions such as cookie files). Based on Webviews used by add-ins, what webview were you using when it last worked and what are you using now? Also, if you create the link statically in the HTML and make the user physically click it, does it work?

I think you've hit upon the key issue.

Reading through that link, there's a reference to Script Lab no longer supporting the Trident webview. My last successful run in April was on desktop M365 on W10. I think that must have been using Trident.
There is a discussion about workarounds for errors when downloading blobs as PDF files. Ostensibly the same thing should work here, though it involves setting up a mini web app outside the office context.
I don't have time to sort that now, so I've reverted to a simple VBA script.
Won't work in the browser, but gets the job done.
So much for trying to move on from VBA...
